# Why does a foreach loop produce different results with similar inputs?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `foreach` loop that takes checkbox data and inserts it into a DB as its own row. In every instance, the first one is successfully inputted while the second and onward fails to enter. I know the data is being read as I echoed it via PHP but it just doesn't insert it into the DB.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $names=$_POST['names'];

    $check=$_SESSION['user'];

    $queryNUMERO2 = "SELECT * FROM `meeting` WHERE chairman='".$check."' ORDER BY id DESC";

    if($resultNUMERO2 = mysqli_query($db, $queryNUMERO2)){

        foreach($names as $user){

            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNUMERO2);

            $meetingId = $row2['id'];
            $meetingDate = $row2['time'];
            $meetingTitle = $row2['title'];

            echo $user;

            $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `usermeet` (`id`, `username`, `date`, `title`) VALUE ('".$meetingId."', '".$user."', '".$meetingDate."', '".$meetingTitle."')";

            if($result = mysqli_query($db, $insertQuery)){

                echo "success";

            }
            else{
                echo "failure";
            }

        }

    }

}
```

When I do it, the input by the server is: (username) then (success) for the first one. Then onward it says (username2) (failure) (username3) (failure) even though it is doing the same query over and over. Can anyone point out why?

I did try `VALUES` in the query but same result either way.

Here is the code where users will tick off the checkbox.

```
      <?php
      $num=0;
      $query = 'SELECT * FROM `users`';
         if(!($result = mysqli_query($db,$query))){
            echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #'.mysqli_errno().': '.mysqli_error();
        }
      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
          echo "

          <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>{$row['firstname']} {$row['lastname']}</th>
             <th><div class=\"form-check\">
                <label class=\"form-check-label\">
                   <input class=\"form-check-input\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"names[]\" id=\"blankCheckbox\" value=\"{$row['username']}\">
                </label>
             </div></th>
             <th></th>
          </tr>
          </form>

        ";
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to duplicate unique keys?  Inserting the same meeting id twice or something.  Check for database errors.

Comment: @Progrock YES that's it I just made a new table with no unique or primary keys and it worked! Thanks a lot man

Comment: @Progrock leave an answer so I can mark the question answered